Stairs placed into new construction
We have stairs that were placed into our new construction home. It looks as if the stairs were exposed to rain prior to being installed. Is this a big deal at this stage of construction?


Where is the water damage?  Was that a used staircase pulled from somewhere else? Nothing in the pic shows water damage.

@RMDman  The OSB and the covering on the side does not look to be in the best condition.  If structural or cosmetic I do not know.

@crip659, all I see is some dirty wood. I can't identify any OSB.  If the construction is new, how did the stairs get white paint and a covering on the treads?  I'm thinking the stairs may be temporary.

It's a common practice for builders to install temporary stairs and use them for access before the floors and walls are finished. the temporary stairs will then be removed and replaced with new stairs.
For peace of mind ask your builder, they probably get asked this same question quite often, so they are unlikely to take offense.

I'm thinking they have to be temporary also.
